# Comment exprimer « to flip the script » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai entendu l'expression anglaise *(to) [flip the script](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flip_the_script#English)*, « (slang) to reverse a situation, especially by doing something unexpected » (Wiktionnaire). Le contexte c'était la compétition et le style des compétiteurs, et on s'attendait à quelque chose de particulier de l'un plutôt que de l'autre, mais finalement c'est ce dernier qui a donné le ton et le commentateur à dit de la personne qu'elle a vraiment « flipped the script »...

Comment le transpose-t-on le plus couramment ? Préfère-t-on employer un verbe avec le sujet ou parler de la situation avec un tour impersonnel : pourquoi ?

Comment: Je veux conserver des choix et j'aimerais ne pas empiéter sur un ou des sens de [_turn around_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turn_around), du genre _to reverse the expected outcome of a game_ mais je ne veux pas devoir comparer la locution de la question avec ça, parce que ça implique une expertise en anglais, et je ne suis pas anglophone etc. Je note aussi qu'on s'est beaucoup souciés du verbe et peu du substantif.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'expression la plus courante est je pense « retourner la situation ».

- Avec cette action inattendue, Untel a retourné la situation à son profit.

Une autre expression peut-être plus proche de *to flip the script* est «  changer la donne ».

- La rentrée de Mbappé a changé la donne.

On parle aussi de « tournant », en particulier « tournant du match » dans un contexte sportif.

- Son but de la main n'a pas été sifflé, c'était le tournant du match !

Comment: @enfernette selon moi ca ne change rien, pour peu qu'il s'agisse d'un match. S'il s'agit d'une course, ca sera le "tournant de la course".

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, ou le tournant de l'épreuve, du concours, de la campagne, de la carrière. Ce n'est pas limité au sport collectif, ni au sport tout court.

Answer (score 1):

La réponse de jlliagre est correcte, mais je voulais ajouter mon grain de sel avec une expression idiomatique:

> un revirement (de situation)

On pourra dire par exemple, en parlant du match

> Quel revirement de situation !

Par contre,  je m'imagine mal dire à un joueur

> Vous avez reviré la situation

ou encore

> Untel a vraiment reviré la situation

Dans de tels cas je pense que je contournerais l'obstacle avec par exemple

> Vous êtes la raison principale de ce revirement

Je ne saurais dire si l'emploi en verbe est incongru, incorrect ou si c'est simplement moi qui ai cette impression.

Comment: Est-ce que je dois comprendre de l'ordre de présentation que tu trouves plus usuel d'employer un substantif (_revirement_) que le verbe (_revirer_) ; pourquoi de prime abord ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas l'impression d'avoir souvent entendu utiliser le verbe, alors que le substantif m'est beaucoup plus familier. Selon moi on utilise plus facilement "retourner" que "revirer"

Answer (score -2):

« Renverser la situation » est une expression très courante qui s'emploie aussi bien dans le langage littéraire que dans le langage courant et qui peut traduire « flip the script ». Pour le moins, elle est synonyme de « retourner  la situation » dans beaucoup de cas où le contexte rend cela apparent.

> [réf. 1, (TLFi, **D.1.**)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/renverser) : 1. Changer, modifier complètement pour quelque chose d'opposé, de différent. Renverser la situation, une théorie, une tendance; renverser des calculs, des principes; renverser les rôles.
>
> [réf. 2, (TLFi, **I.A.2.a)**)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/retourner) : ♦ Retourner la situation. Prendre l'avantage alors qu'on avait le dessous. Les Américains comptaient sur lui pour prendre le commandement des troupes françaises d'Afrique du Nord et retourner la situation (De Gaulle, Mém. guerre, 1956, p. 42).

> [réf. 3](https://books.google.fr/books?id=YMp7BwAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&dq=%22renvers%C3%A9+la+situation%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj635Hz4OPnAhUuxoUKHR53DEAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22renvers%C3%A9%20la%20situation%22&f=false) : Sortilèges de la séduction : Lectures critiques de Shakespeare, books.google.fr › books
>   André Green - 2005 -
>
> - Ainsi, après avoir renversé la situation à son profit et fait perdre à Brutus les avantages que sa plaidoirie lui avait assurés auprès du peuple, ayant à pactiser momentanément avec les assassins de César, Marc Antoine verse quelques larmes …

Il n'est pas nécessaire d'utiliser le mot « situation » bien que ce soit un mot très courant dans ce contexte ; des termes plus aptes selon le contexte peuvent sembler préférables.

- Jean courait bien plus vite que Pierre qui avait deux ans de moins mais ce dernier a renversé l'inégalité comme il a atteint la puberté. (user **LPH**)

Un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=renvers%C3%A9+la+situation%2Crenverser+la+situation%2Crenversement+de+la+situation&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crenvers%C3%A9%20la%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crenverser%20la%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crenversement%20de%20la%20situation%3B%2Cc0) montre que le substantif qui correspond est d'emploi plus fréquent que l'ensemble des constructions avec « renversé la situation » mais pas, depuis quelques temps, plus fréquent que  l'expression utilisant l'infinitif.

Cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=renvers%C3%A9+la+situation%2Crenverser+la+situation%2Crenversement+de+la+situation%2Cretourn%C3%A9+la+situation%2Cretourner+la+situation%2Cretournement+de+la+situation&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crenvers%C3%A9%20la%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crenverser%20la%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crenversement%20de%20la%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cretourn%C3%A9%20la%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cretourner%20la%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cretournement%20de%20la%20situation%3B%2Cc0) montre que chacune des formes synonymes, « retourné la situation », « retourner la situation » et « retournement de la situation » est utilisée  avec une fréquence comparable respectivement à la forme de même construction pour le verbe « renverser ».

[DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#fr/en/renverserlasituation%2C%0A) confirme que « reverse the situation » est une traduction possible.

Une forme pronominale est disponible, « la situation < se renverser > » ([Ac.](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/renverser?page=1), [TLFi **D.1;**, Empl. Pronom. Passif](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/renverser)).

> Même si les chances de la guerre se renversaient (...) l'immense et profond ébranlement de l'esprit public russe ne serait point amorti (Jaurès,Paix menacée, 1914, p. 102).

L'emploi pronominal de sens passif est documenté [ici](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2957). Dans ce cas aussi la forme correspondante avec le verbe « retourner » est utilisée de nos jours selon une fréquence comparable ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+situation+s%27est+renvers%C3%A9e%2Cla+situation+s%27est+retourn%C3%A9e&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20situation%20s%27est%20renvers%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20situation%20s%27est%20retourn%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0)). Selon ce que je peux comprendre, les formes pronominales, qui donnent à  l'agent plus ou moins plausible de l'action un rôle passif, sont choisies lorsque l'on trouve plus important de considérer l'évènement lui-même ou ses conséquences (qui peuvent être jugées d'une porté dépassant leur impact sur les responsables), ou lorsque l'on veut souligner son caractère fortuit ou surprenant et aussi, parmi d'autres possibilités, lorsque il s'agit d'un processus dont les responsables (agents) ne sont pas uniques ou pas aisément définissables. À mon avis il n'y a pas de préférence arbitraire dans l'utilisation d'un tour de « passivisation » de l'agent.

- Le club était vraiment l'un des pires et personne ne voulait joindre l'équipe, jusqu'à ce que la situation commence à se renverser avec la venue de X  et plus tard de Y, des joueurs qui ont beaucoup fait pour rehausser sa réputation. (user **LPH**)
- Aux États Unis, cet état de choses qui consistait  à préférer presque uniquement les voitures de grande taille s'est soudainement renversé et pratiquement toutes les grandes voitures ont été remplacées  par des véhicules plus petits.  (user **LPH**)

Comment: 1/ Pourquoi "user LPH" plutôt que "utilisateur LPH" dans une réponse en français? 2/ *mais ce dernier a renversé l'inégalité comme il a atteint la puberté* n'est pas idiomatique, pas plus que la dernière phrase (ces sont les **grosses** voitures, qui ont été remplacées, pas les **grandes** voitures).

Comment: @jlliagre 1/ J'utilise « user » plutôt que « utilisateur » parce que le système FSE (French Stack Exchange) est fondé sur l'anglais américain (par exemple : Home, Questions, Tags, Users, Unanswered ; aussi user 17649, OP) ; comme cela, il y a une plus grande certitude qu'il s'agit du système ; après tout, s'il n'y a plus les signatures « LPH » dans les commentaires « LPH » c'est n'importe quoi. 2/ Je ne veux pas introduire de différence  « grand/grosse » dans ce contexte : L'anglais après le bac: BTS, IUT... - Christian Bouscaren, ‎Claude Rivière - 1993 - ‎a big car, une grande voiture.

Comment: @jlliagre 3/ « Renverser l'inégalité » est constructif, selon un modèle ; example « manger quelque chose/manger des rats, manger de la glaise, manger du kaolin, manger du souffre, … » ; il n'y a donc pas à questionner l'idiomaticité. De plus on trouve cette combinaison : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=renverser+l%27in%C3%A9galit%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crenverser%20l%27%20in%C3%A9galit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crenverser%20l'%20in%C3%A9galit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0.

Comment: Tu confonds interface utilisateur et contenu. Tu as bien tort de ne pas différencier grand et gros, la Grosse-Bretagne pourrait s'en vexer. Tu ne comprends pas ce qui n'est pas idiomatique dans tes phrases.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne crois pas la différence très importante dans **ce contexte** mais je dois dire que je suis conscient que « grosse voiture » est bien plus courant.

Comment: @enfernette Non, les grosses voitures aux États Unis ont été remplacées par des petites voitures ou des « commpact-cars »: https://www.francetvinfo.fr/replay-radio/l-auto/voitures-americaines-toujours-ces-autos-gigantesques-et-demesurees_1743001.html […] des années 70.
Depuis cette époque, les constructeurs américains: les "big three" : General Motors, Ford, et Chrysler  ont diminué la taille de leurs voitures.
Elles ont  des proportions beaucoup plus européennes […]. De toutes façons cela n'est pas important, ce qui compte c'est les rapports sémantiques et vous négligez cela entièrement.