# Le « renversement des rôles » : étendue du sens et fréquence d'emploi ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, locutions, lexique, fréquence-utilisation

Dans le cadre d'une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/41261), j'ai pensé au « renversement des rôles ». On en trouve deux exemples dans une oeuvre :

> Par un incroyable et fabuleux **renversement des rôles**, lui, le chef
>   suprême, dans ce couvent où tout était à lui: choses et gens, où tout
>   lui obéissait au geste, il était le prisonnier de cet aventurier qu'il
>   croyait tenir dans sa main puissante, et qui maintenant pouvait d'un
>   geste détruire, avec sa vie, tout ce qu'il représentait de puissance,
>   de richesse, d'autorité, d'ambition.
>
> ---
>
> Il jeta sur celui dont il était le prisonnier—par un **renversement de
>   rôles** inouï d'audace—un regard d'admiration sincère en même temps
>   qu'un soupir douloureux trahissait le désespoir que lui causait sa
>   défaite.
>
> [ [*Les Pardaillan*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/13727/13727-h/13727-h.htm) — Tome 06 : Les amours du Chico de [Michel
>   Zévaco](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Z%C3%A9vaco) ]

Mais en cherchant, je ne le trouve pas au [dictionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/clivages) semble-t-il alors je suis un peu perplexe, d'autant plus que personne ne l'a évoqué dans l'autre question, et que je connais en anglais le *(complete) [role reversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role_reversal)*.

Alors je me demande si ce serait aujourd'hui un calque ou si c'est employé fréquemment, si c'est un emploi peut-être plus régional (Québec) ou si ça relève plutôt d'un emploi technique en psychologie ou autrement et incidemment si ça constituerait le cas échéant une extension de sens abusive dans le contexte de la question liée, par exemple ; ou est-ce simplement un exemple d'un truc qui n'est pas documenté ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Renversement des rôles* est tout à fait idiomatique et attesté depuis longtemps en français.

Depuis une soixantaine d'années, *inversion des rôles* concurrence cette première expression et est aujourd'hui plus populaire.

[image]

Comment: D'accord mais as-tu une idée de la raison pour laquelle on ne trouve pas ça très facilement, ce n'est pas un truc figé ou c'est purement une lacune documentaire ? Et pourquoi disons ça n'est pas sorti dans la question sur _to flip the script_, rétroactivement trouves-tu qu'il y a adéquation ? Est-ce que ça peut être employé au figuré comme au propre (parent/enfant, par exemple) ?

Comment: Oui, ce n'est pas vraiment une locution figée. *Inverser les rôles* peut en effet convenir pour *flip the script* d'autant plus qu'on reste dans le même domaine avec un script et des rôles. C'est aussi courant au sens figuré.